# Why some codes are colourful, some aren't in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: angularjs, text, colors, editor, sublimetext3

I had created angular quick start but as I mentioned in title some codes aren't colourful. How can I solve this?

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is because sublime will look at the extension and try to decide what kind of syntax is used in the file. In other words `ts` are not mapped to any syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default sublime check extension of file and set highlighting for language (based on extension). For your case he knows that `.js` is javascript but he **does not recognize** `.ts` extension so he choosed *plain text*.

If sublime does not recognize which language the file has you can still define language in file manually.

In the **right bottom corner** in Sublime you can see for second file the "syntax highlighting" is set to Plain text.

[image]

Click on plain text and select javascript for example:

[image]